# Can korma/fields take an array of columns?

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I would like to be able to pass a user-defined array of fields which contains a list of all the columns that need fetching. Can korma/fields take an array of columns?

What I am essentially wanting to create is something like this:

```
(defn fetch [fields]
(->
   (korma/select* foo)

   (as-> query
         (if (not-empty? fields)
           (korma/fields query fields)
           query))

   (korma/select)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming this is because I have specified entity-fields in defentity. I am therefore wondering, if it is possible to override the entity-fields specified in `defentity`?

I think your assumption is correct, and it's also possible to override this. If you look at the map generated by `(defentity foo)` it has a `:fields` key with all the fields. [`korma.core/entity-fields`](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/857a3fcc031e07339ec6d810e7f3e2ef9a773804/src/korma/core.clj#L677) doesn't *replace* what's already there, but this will:

```
(-> foo
    (assoc :fields [:first])
    (korma/select*)
    (korma/as-sql))
=> "SELECT \"foo\".\"first\" FROM \"foo\""
```

> I would like to be able to pass a user-defined array of fields which contains a list of all the columns that need fetching.

```
(defn fetch [& fields]
  (-> (korma/select* foo)
      (as-> query
        (if (seq fields)
          (assoc query :fields fields)
          query))
      (korma/select)))
```

I used variadic args in this example to mirror `korma.core/entity-fields` (and made `fetch` return the SQL string for my testing rather than execute the query):

```
(fetch :first :last)
=> "SELECT \"foo\".\"first\", \"foo\".\"last\" FROM \"foo\""
(fetch)
=> "SELECT \"foo\".\"id\", \"foo\".\"first\", \"foo\".\"last\" FROM \"foo\""
```